# Sed from Serial Stream

Tags: regex, linux, sed, cat

I'm using a Raspberry Pi with a Serial device connected over USB (/dev/ttyACM0).
I can write the data to the console with `cat /dev/ttyACM0`.

But when I try to replace the $ signs in the output with a newline `cat /dev/ttyACM0 | sed 's/\$/\n/g'` i get no output.

When I write the output of `cat` to a file and then replace the `$` signs with `cat file | sed 's/\$/\n/g'` it works.

Is there any option for sed that it will work?

Comment: did you try  `cat /dev/ttyACM0 | sed "s/\$/\n/g"` (or `sed --unbuffered "s/\$/\n/g" /dev/ttyACM0`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this I'm pretty sure that it will work,

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0 | tr '$' '\n'
```

Comment: Right, `sed` waits to receive a full line of text, but `tr` will make replacements char by char.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sed`'s option `--unbuffered`.